# Showing that the dotted arrow can not be filled in with a continuous function making the diagram commutes.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

This Theorem is assumed to be taken for granted:

$S^1$ is not contractible.

Now I want to use it to Show that the dotted arrow can not be filled in with a continuous function making the following diagram commutes.

> $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> S^0 @>{id_{S^0}}>> S^0\\
> @VVV @VVV \\
> D^1 @>{?}>> S^0
> \end{CD}$$
>
> where the arrow below $?$ should be a dotted arrow because we are searching for this function. And I am not skillful in drawing commutative diagrams this is why I draw $S^0$ 2 times because I do not know how to draw one dotted arrow coming out of $D^1$ going directly to $S^0$ my bad. Then my job is to show that there can be no such function $?$

**My thoughts:**

I know that if there were such function, call it $r.$ And if I call the function from $S^0$ to $D^1$ say $j$ then by the commutativity of the diagram I would have $r \circ j = id_{S^0}.$ But how this would contradict that $S^1$ being not contractible ? I know that contractible means homotopically equivalent to the one point space $*.$

Any help with directing my thoughts in the right direction please?

Comment: The map on the right is assumed to be the identity as well?

Comment: @PrudiiArca sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb S^0 =\{\pm 1\}$ is disconnected and $\Bbb D^1 =[0,1]$ is connected, hence there is no surjective continuous map $\Bbb D^1 \rightarrow \Bbb S^0$ and in particular no retraction to $\Bbb S^0$.

More interesting is the question, whether $\Bbb S^1$ is a deformation retract of $\Bbb D^k$ for any $k\geq 1$, ie. if there is an embedding $m:\Bbb S^1 \rightarrow \Bbb D^k$ and a retraction $r:\Bbb D^k \rightarrow \Bbb S^1$ satisfying $rm = \operatorname{id}_{\Bbb S^1}$ and $mr \sim \operatorname{id}_{\Bbb D^k}$. However, as deformation retracts constitute homotopy equivalences and all $\Bbb D^k$ are contractible, ie. homotopy equivalent to $*$, the knowledge that $\Bbb S^1$ is **not contractible**, answers this question to the negative as well.

Comment: I do not understand your first line ... why we are sure that "there is no surjective continuous map $\mathbb{D}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^0$" could you explain this please?

Comment: The image of a connected space under a continuous map is again connected. Thus every map $\Bbb D^1 \rightarrow \Bbb S^0$ is constant and in particular does not hit either 1 or $-1$.

Comment: I agree with your first statement but I do not understand your second statement .... why every map is constant ? why it does not hit either 1 or -1?

Comment: Because $\{-1,+1\}$ has two connected components, namely $\{-1\}$ and $\{1\}$. Any continuous map from a connected space into a disconnected space can only hit one of the connected components

Comment: but why it does not hit either $1$ or $-1$? you said it can hit one of the connected components.

Comment: You have to map somewhere, right? So if you hit 1 you have to be constant 1, since $\{1\}$ is a connected component of $\Bbb S^0$. Likewise for -1

Comment: So your statement that it does not hit either is incorrect .... I think you meant to say it does not hit both .... am I correct?

Comment: Oh right. Sorry for creating this misunderstanding. In German this might have been clearer (or similarly unclear I guess), maybe I mistranslated :(